# Akka - How to restart a child spawned by a router?

Tags: java, akka, akka-supervision

I have an `Actor` that creates children using a `Router`. When one of the children fail. I'm being notified in the startegy about the failure. However the `Actor` does not restart by itself.

```
private static SupervisorStrategy strategy = new OneForOneStrategy(10, Duration.create("1 minute"),
        throwable -> {
            Directive directive;
            if (throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                directive = SupervisorStrategy.restart();
            } else {
                directive = SupervisorStrategy.stop();
            }
            return directive;
        });
```

I also found out from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839983/akka-actor-kill-restart-behavior) that if a child of a `Router` terminates, the `Router` will not automatically spawn a new child. And also, when all of the router's children terminate, the `Router` terminates itself as well.

Now the million dollar question - What is the right way to restart a child that was spawned by a `Router`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using a `Pool` router (it starts its own children). Instead what you want to use is a `Group` router ([group router docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/scala/routing.html#Group)) in which case you create the child Actors and supply them to the router. This means that you're in charge (you as in the parent actor of these routees) is fully in  charge of their lifecycle. So there you'd define the supervision strategy in the parent and all works as you'd want it to then.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `RoundRobinPool`. Will use a group and get back to you on this. Thank you.